# The series $\sum_n\Gamma (n-1/3)/(n-1)!$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, gamma-function

I would like to prove that the series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma (n-1/3)}{(n-1)!}$$
diverges. The problem is that I don't know how to begin.

Intuitively I get the result, because observing the terms of the series as they're summed up the sum gets bigger and bigger and it blows up.

Any ideas would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: show that

$$\frac{c}{n^{1/3}}\le\frac{\Gamma (n-1/3)}{(n-1)!},$$

for some positive constant $c>1$ and use the comparison test. $c=2$ works.

Comment: Thank you... This is not homework actually... but it came up as an exercise of an integral I was solving... That will defintely do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Let

$$u_n=\frac{\Gamma(n-1/3)}{(n-1)!}$$
then by the relation
$$\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$$
we have
$$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{n-1/3}{n}=1-\frac{\frac13}{n}$$
hence  by the [Raabe-Duhamel's rule](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A8gle_de_Raabe-Duhamel) the series is divergent.

Comment: In english: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Raabe-Duhamel.27s_test

Comment: Very nice answer! Thank you as well.

Comment: You're welcome @Tolaso and thanks to Jean-Claude for this link:-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that $$\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{\Gamma (n-1/3)}{(n-1)!}=\frac{3 \Gamma \left(m+\frac{2}{3}\right)}{2 \Gamma (m)}$$ May be, you could use induction to prove it and go to the limit.

If you approximate the rhs using Stirling approximation, you end with $$\frac{3 \Gamma \left(m+\frac{2}{3}\right)}{2 \Gamma (m)} \simeq \frac{3 (m-1)^{\frac{1}{2}-m} \left(m-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{m+\frac{1}{6}}}{2 e^{2/3}} > \frac{3 (m-1)^{2/3}}{2 e^{2/3}}$$

Comment: How did you come up with this equality?

Comment: Not by hand ! I was curious and used a CAS just to look at the problem. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

For every $a\gt-1$, $b\gt0$, $b\ne a+1$, one has $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\Gamma (k+a)}{\Gamma(k+b)}=\frac1{a+1-b}\left(\frac{\Gamma(n+a+1)}{\Gamma(n+b)}-\frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(b)}\right).$$
Taking the limit $b\to0$ yields, for every $a\gt-1$, $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\Gamma (k+a)}{(k-1)!}=\frac1{a+1}\frac{\Gamma(n+a+1)}{(n-1)!}.$$
The formula in @ClaudeLeibovici's post is the case $a=-1/3$.